# tags merging and news

Tags: feature-request, specific-tag, merge-tag-request

Shalom!

I want to know if people are interested to merge the tags "mishnah" and "mishnayot". I feel that to merge all in mishnah may make the search easiest. 
In my mind "mishnayot" may be a subgroup of the topics of mishnayot that point the specific learning of mishnayot. But it is not necessary.

For special problems of talmudical and midrashic hermeneutic, I mean Sifra, Mechilta and Sifrey, I am interested to know if people mean that to add specific tags is beneficial. Maybe "Halachic hermeneutic", I really don't find a right expression. In Hebrew I think that דרשות שהתורה נדרשת בהן is right. May include 13 middot of Rabbi Yishmael, 32 middot of Rabbi Eliezer son of RY Haglili. 7 of Hillel. Maybe 13 middot is good but it is confusing with 13 middot of Rachamim, and do not include some Drashot as Ribuy Umyut. 
I submit the issue to specialists.

Comment: mishna, mishnah and mishnayos are already synonyms from what I can see

Comment: If you have enough reputation in the tag, you can add them as suggested synonyms. There are still a few synonyms waiting to be voted on [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) (from as long ago as 2012; it seems not enough people find that page)